# laravel adding amount in loop if the rank does not exists

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I have a rank for every user that will tell how much the amount they will receive. But the if the user with that rank does not exist, it will go through the next user, because the rank are in order.

Rank (in order):

```
Basic - 50
Junior - 100
Premium - 150
Advanced - 200
Senior - 250
```

each of those ranks does have a corresponding value, and that value will be added to the next user if it does not exist. I just want to ask if my code is ok or it can be refactored.

My code:

```
$ranks = collect([
    (object) ['name' => 'Basic', 'amount' => 50],
    (object) ['name' => 'Junior',  'amount' => 100],
    (object) ['name' => 'Premium',  'amount' => 150],
    (object) ['name' => 'Advanced',  'amount' => 200],
    (object) ['name' => 'Senior',  'amount' => 250],
]);

$users = collect([
    (object) ['rank' => 'Basic', 'amount' => 0],
    (object) ['rank' => 'Junior', 'amount' => 0],
    (object) ['rank' => 'Premium', 'amount' => 0],
    (object) ['rank' => 'Senior', 'amount' => 0],
]);

$amount_to_transfer = 0;
$available_ranks = $users->pluck('rank');
        
foreach($ranks as $rank){
    if(!in_array($rank->name, $available_ranks->toArray()))
    {
        $amount_to_transfer += $rank->amount;
    } else {
        $usersOfThisRank = $users->filter(function($usr, $key) use($rank){
            return $usr->rank == $rank->name;
        });
            $usersOfThisRank->map(function($usr, $key) use($rank, $amount_to_transfer){
            $usr->amount += $rank->amount + $amount_to_transfer;
        });
    }
}

dd($amount_to_transfer);
```

Comment: can you include your desire output,

Comment: just do `if(empty($rank)) { continue }`  https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll keep using `(object)`, here's how I'd do it. This way we don't need as many variables and it's shorter.

I'm assuming you only have one user for each rank.

```php
$accumulated = 0;
$ranks->each(function ($rank) use (&$accumulated, $users) {
    if ( !$users->contains('rank', $rank->name) ) {
        $accumulated += $rank->amount;
    } else {
        $user = $users->firstWhere('rank', $rank->name);
        $user->amount = $accumulated + $rank->amount;
        $accumulated = 0;
    }
});
```

This question is more suited for  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've posted a more explained question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251574/laravel-iteration-adding-value-to-the-next-user-if-the-user-rank-does-not-exist